# Copying files within Electron application results in 'no such file or directory' error. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to copy a file to a folder in my Electron application but I keep getting a no such directory/file error.

I am new to this, so I could be missing something completely obvious. I keep getting this error,

> ```
> `Failed to copy the file: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile       'C:\Users\AJSWI\Downloads\unnamed.png' -> 'C:\Users\AJSWI\Desktop\College    Notes\CollegeNotes\Classes\F2324\Math\unnamed.png'] {
> ```
>
> errno: -4058,
> code: 'ENOENT',
> syscall: 'copyfile',
> path: 'C:\Users\AJSWI\Downloads\unnamed.png',
> dest: 'C:\Users\AJSWI\Desktop\College Notes\CollegeNotes\Classes\F2324\Math\unnamed.png'
> }`

I have double checked everything that I could think of, the path exists, I removed the name at the end of the destination, and I even asked ChatGPT which went nowhere.
here is the function I use to check and copy the file.

- btw the console.log passed check appears in the console -

> `fs.access(noteFile, fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
> if (err) {
> console.error('Source file does not exist:', err);
> return;
> }
> console.log("Passed Check - ", noteFile);
>
> fs.copyFile(noteFile, destination, (err) => {
> if (err) {
> console.error('Failed to copy the file:', err);
> return; }
> console.log('File copied to:', destination);
> });
>
> });`